# Paging3 Dynamic filtering not working as expected

Tags: android, android-paging-3

I am currently working on implementing paging functionality using **Paging3**, incorporating **user-input filtering** for item titles. The implementation is generally successful, except for a **peculiar scenario**:

When the combination of the **Flow<PagingData>** and the **Filter flow** occurs, if the **first page** in the PagingData is filtered out (resulting in 0 elements remaining), the **PagingDataAdapter** does not request any additional pages. However, if you have already scrolled through several pages and this particular element is in the cache (via `.cachedIn(viewModelScope)`), the functionality works perfectly.

I am uncertain whether passing an **empty PagingData** in the **initial flow combine** misleads the adapter into assuming that **endOfPagination** has been reached or this is the normal functionality.

| First page loaded | All Paged Loaded |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Only first page has loaded] | [image: Result after all pages have been loaded] |

These are my paging classes:

## PagingSource

```
class SchoolPagingSource (
    private var schoolDataBase: SchoolDataBase
) : PagingSource<Int,School>() {

    companion object{
        const val ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 20
    }
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, School> {

        val nextPageNumber = params.key ?: 1
        val nextElementPosition = (nextPageNumber - 1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE

        return try {
            var response = schoolDataBase.schoolDao().getSchools(ITEMS_PER_PAGE,nextElementPosition)
            
            val key = if (response.size == ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
                nextPageNumber + 1
            else
                null
            
            LoadResult.Page(response, null, key)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
    
    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, School>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            val anchorPage = state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)
            anchorPage?.prevKey?.plus(1) ?: anchorPage?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }
}
```

## ViewModel

```
class SchoolsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dataBase: SchoolDataBase,
) : BaseViewModel() {

    private val _filterStringState = MutableStateFlow("")

    //TODO ARREGLAR

    fun getAllSchools(): Flow<PagingData<School>> =
        Pager(config =
        PagingConfig(
            pageSize = ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
            prefetchDistance = 20,
            enablePlaceholders = true
        )) {
            SchoolPagingSource(dataBase)
        }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope).combine(_filterStringState) { pagingData, string ->
            pagingData.filter {
                it.getName()
                    .contains(
                        string
                    )
            }
        }.cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    fun filterByString(string: String) = launch { _filterStringState.emit(string) }

}
```

## PagingDataAdapter

```
class SchoolsPagingDataAdapter() :
    PagingDataAdapter<School, SchoolsPagingDataAdapter.ViewHolder>(SCHOOL_COMPARATOR) {

    companion object{
        private val SCHOOL_COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<School>(){
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: School, newItem: School): Boolean =
                oldItem.id == newItem.id

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: School, newItem: School): Boolean =
                oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,viewType: Int): ViewHolder =
       ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_colegio, parent, false)
       )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.bind(getItem(position))

    inner class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {}
```

I kinda fixed it using `adapter.refresh()` but is has its own problems

## Fragment

```
schoolFragment.setOnSearchTextWatcher {
            schoolViewModel.filterByString(it)
            if (adapterSchools.snapshot().isEmpty() && !endOfPaginationReached) {
                adapterSchools.refresh()
                endOfPaginationReached = true
            }
        }
adapterSchools.addLoadStateListener { loadState ->
    if (loadState.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading && loadState.append.endOfPaginationReached)
       endOfPaginationReached = true
}
```

Comment: Returning 'null' as the next key means no more values to load further for the next part. You are passing null as the next key when the data size does not equal to ITEMS_PER_PAGE. I believe that would be the reason for the data not showing up. You can read the example's comments from the following link

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingSource#presenting-data-to-ui